# How to sleep or wait in pioneerjs test?

Tags: testing, cucumber

I would like wait X seconds:

```
Background:
    Given I open the game
    And I wait for 10 seconds
```

And the commands

```
this.Given(/^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/,function(n){
    this.driver.sleep(n.to_i)
});
```

This doesn't work, any idea on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this but it might not be the best way to do it:

```
this.Given(/^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/,function(n){
    var timerDone = false;
    setTimeout(function(){
        timerDone = true;
    }, n * 1000)
    this.driver.wait(function(){
        return timerDone;
    }, Infinity).then(function(){
        console.log("end")
    })
});
```